# List items are not shown as well as can't add new items in list dynemically

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

### these code is not allowing me to add new item into the list as well as already added list items are not showing. the button symbol is not displaying. **list.ejs**     To Do List

## <%= listTitle %>

  <% for(var i=0;i<=newListItems.length; i++) %> <% { %>
  <%= newListItems[i] %>
  <% } %>

<button type="submit" name="button" value=<%= listTitle %>+     **app.js** const express = require("express"); const bodyParser = require("body-parser"); const app = express(); let items =["Buy Food","Cook Food","Eat Food"]; let workItems=[]; app.set('view engine','ejs'); app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true})); app.use(express.static("public")); app.get("/", function(req, res){ let today = new Date(); let options={ weekday:"long", day:"numeric", month:"long" }; let day=today.toLocaleDateString("en-US",options); res.render("list",{listTitle:day , newListItems:items}); }); app.post("/",function(req,res){ let item = req.body.newItem; if(req.body.list === "Work"){ workItems.push(item); res.redirect("/work"); } else{ items.push(item); res.redirect("/"); } }); app.get("/work",function(req,res){ res.render("list",{listTitle:"Work List", newListItems:workItems}); }); app.listen(3000, function(){ console.log("Server started on port 3000."); });

Comment: You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and this [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Code that you have worked on to solve the problem should include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and be included in your question.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
  <%= listTitle %>     
 <% for(var i=0; i < newListItems.length; i++) %>
            <% { %>
                <%= newListItems[i] %>

                    <% } %>
          <form action="/" method="POST">
              <input type="text" name="newItem">
              <button type="submit" name="button"><%=listTitle %></button>
          </form>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I tried to use above code but still it's not allowing to enter array items..

Answer (score 0):

```
app.post("/", function(req,res){
  let item = req.body.newItem;
  if(req.body.list === "Work List"){
    workItems.push(item);
    res.redirect("/work");
  } else {
    items.push(item);
    res.redirect("/");
  }
});
```